# ¿Cómo hago una alerta con un mensaje de error de usuario o contraseña incorrectos?

Tags: php, ajax, login

Necesito hacer una alerta con el `ajax` para que me indique que el **usuario** o las **contraseñas** son incorrectas.

este es mi código:

**`AJAX JQUERY`**

```
function Validar() {
  var datos = $("#formulario").serialize(); //toma los datos "name" y los lleva 
  aun arreglo.
  $.ajax({
       url: "php/verifica3.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: datos,
       success: function(texto) {
       if (texto == 'exito') {
          correcto();
       } else {
          phperror();
       }
     }     
  });
}
```

**`HTML`**

```
 <form class="user"   onsubmit="Validar()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" name="email" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingrese Email..." required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Clave" required>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Acceder" id="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
 </form>
```

**`PHP`**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    $error = '';
    require_once "user.php";
    $usuario = new user();

    $resultado=json_decode($usuario- >getValidUser($_POST['email'],$_POST['password']));

if($resultado[0]->existe>0)
{
  echo "exito";
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $resultado[0]->user_id;   
  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['email'];   
  $_SESSION['firstname'] = $resultado[0]->firstname;
  $_SESSION['lastname'] = $resultado[0]->lastname;
  $_SESSION['start'] = time();
  $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60000 * 10);
  header('Location: index.php');
} else {
      echo "error";
      exit;
}
?>
```

Pero no me esta funcionando podrían ayudarme Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual seria especificamente el problema?

Comment: Probaste o que te parece usar sweet alert? puede personalizarse. https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/